# simple injector ASP.NET MVC post form result error

Tags: dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm new with simple injector, register all instances as described in guide on codeplex and nuget package. All works fine when I'm clicking on links, which relates to actions without form back result.

When I have a form with some data inputed and after submit button clicked, for any get or post method I have an error like container not initialized:

"No parameterless constructor defined for this object."

Cannot figure out why this was happened.

Comment: Please show your configuration, controller in question, stacktrace, and other related information.

Comment: Did you include this NuGet package? http://nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.MVC3

Comment: problem solved, it is not related to simple-injector, but relates to requirement to use parameterless constructor for model, used in view. I have constructor with parameter with default value, as result have an error.